# Dialogflow v2 error “MalformedResponse 'final_response' must be set”

Tags: python, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am getting this error only when using the simulator/google assistant. When I use the Slack integration or test within DialogFlow then it works perfectly.

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004983/malformed-response-final-response-must-be-set) about settings in DialogFlow, but that wasn't my issue. I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701802/how-to-solve-malformedresponse-final-response-must-be-set-error-in-action-sim) but because I use **python** in my webhook, I can't be sure whether that would solve it for me or not.

I am doing the following:

First, the user invokes any one of my intents which are connected through a webhook to my python code. Call this `intent1`.

Second, I check to see what the response (`response1`) would be for `intent1` in my code.

Third, I send `response1` to another intent `intent2` via a followup-event `event2`.

The reason why I'm doing this just for interest is that I'm allowing multiple types of conversation flows. The first being FAQs and the second being a directed conversation.

The JSON I'm sending back is:

```
"followupEventInput":{  
              "name":"EventName",
              "parameters":{
                  "speech": str(speech)
                  }
              }
```

`EventName` is `event2`.

`speech` is `response1`

I also tried adding this to the JSON, but it didn't change anything:

```
,"payload": {"google":{"expectUserResponse": False}}
```

---

The Debug from the simulator shows:

```
{
  "response": "",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "GidzaW11bG...",
  "audioResponse": "//NExAASWK...",
  "debugInfo": {
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=2b0fcc112a9b40c48f7a7182a29f6b2f' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQxMjlkYjJlYTE4NjBkMmU4NzFlZTQ4NTA2Mjg3ZmIwNWIwNGNhM2YifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJkbmFmaXQtZmFxIiwiZXhwIjoxNTMwODU5MzIzLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJqdGkiOiJiNDcwZjdhODYyYWJiMzI0NjRjNGY5MmU4MTQ1ZWU5NTFlYTA1MWY5IiwiaWF0IjoxNTMwODU5MjAzLCJuYmYiOjE1MzA4NTg5MDN9.XMAmItiH9SEo1I24T5xEPvSfP7dPX21AYHvVqZZReayNoR396ZQ1JdHZiY9rwGfp49qSwn2ea9EDkNVCQ-PK8NIKdTdxG-L0HuhY7r8nEMfzO4PjJKU6bI-Ry1OwL3A90WGK0l8rwJpByHSfA1gTsS7PU983yyR51PCJFkVnd2KQfX1ZKPIqpcEzKkCvexh9mwOx8cH6iVYuBzmHctH1FRLqhzzRb9zcx3Qq2mDFB8cVbl8SluXLyV4hBeKSeFe-HnkWEzqE3zvgIbAZha2rAOMb2xx1ta_M86hmwET4woAB-hBlR77cyNZV49Y5GmFrF5DozvQWEw1GNoRxcZCLhA'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHEpW9IVOkzk8egeV0A0NHO5Ug4wqLj3ney3hdwx_iPW4cMeayYws8m-fzoFiYksk7JsnDmi-g\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-07-05T15:54:50Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1530859188209\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.TEXT\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"what are the best recipes for oranges\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"text\",\"rawText\":\"what are the best recipes for oranges\",\"textValue\":\"what are the best recipes for oranges\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}'",
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHEpW9IVOkzk8egeV0A0NHO5Ug4wqLj3ney3hdwx_iPW4cMeayYws8m-fzoFiYksk7JsnDmi-g\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-07-05T15:54:50Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1530859188209\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.TEXT\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"what are the best recipes for oranges\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"text\",\"rawText\":\"what are the best recipes for oranges\",\"textValue\":\"what are the best recipes for oranges\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}"
    },
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\n  \"responseMetadata\": {\n    \"status\": {\n      \"code\": 10,\n      \"message\": \"Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response\",\n      \"details\": [{\n        \"@type\": \"type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value\",\n        \"value\": \"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"63a2647e-43fc-4c36-9067-5c48b51626bb\\\",\\\"timestamp\\\":\\\"2018-07-06T06:40:04.014Z\\\",\\\"lang\\\":\\\"en-us\\\",\\\"result\\\":{},\\\"status\\\":{\\\"code\\\":200,\\\"errorType\\\":\\\"success\\\"},\\\"sessionId\\\":\\\"1530859188209\\\"}\"\n      }]\n    }\n  }\n}"
    },
    "sharedDebugInfoList": [
      {
        "name": "ResponseValidation",
        "debugInfo": "",
        "subDebugEntryList": [
          {
            "name": "MalformedResponse",
            "debugInfo": "'final_response' must be set.",
            "subDebugEntryList": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": ""
  },
  "clientError": 0,
  "is3pResponse": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `agentToAssistantJson` field includes the message "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response". As it suggests, whatever you're sending in your response is missing speech information.

You don't specify what Event2 is doing, what it is sending back, or what it is doing with the parameter (if anything), but the likely issue is that it isn't sending back anything. Just including the speech as a parameter doesn't do anything - parameters are just information, not replies.

While there are some uses for followup events, most of the time they aren't what you really want. If you want to reply with a message from the fulfillment - just reply with the message.